# Trouble getting duplicate counts in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find a way to perform some counts of duplicated emails/account numbers in SQL.  The Act_no and Act_emails in this data are not linked (Meaning 1 Act_no does not necessarily have the same email).

```
 | P_key | Salesman | Act_No |  Act_Email |     Date/Time    |
 |   1   |   Max    |   1    | doe@xx.com | 2014-04-13 09:00 |
 |   2   |   Max    |   2    | doe@xx.com | 2014-04-13 08:00 |
 |   3   |   Max    |   2    | cat@xx.com | 2014-04-13 08:00 |
 |   4   |   Sue    |   2    | mom@xx.com | 2014-04-13 08:00 |
 |   5   |   Sue    |   3    | cat@xx.com | 2014-04-13 09:00 |
 |   6   |   Joe    |   4    | x_x@xx.com | 2014-04-13 10:00 |
 |   8   |   Joe    |   5    | mom@xx.com | 2014-04-13 09:00 |
 |   7   |   Joe    |   2    | zip@xx.com | 2014-04-13 11:00 |
```

What I need to do with this information is the following:

I need to get a count of duplicated Act_Emails or Act_Nos for this entire table for each salesman
      - So Max would show 3 for all of his records (due to doe@xx.com in the table twice for max and cat@xx.com being in the table more than once(even though cat@xx.com in only in max once).
      - Joe would show a count of 2 of his records because mom@xx.com (P_key's 4 and 8) AND Act_No 2 (P_keys 2,3,4, and 7) are both in the table more than once, but x_x@xx.com and Act_no 4 are only in the table once.

The next part I am also having trouble with and honestly don't know where to go.  What I need to do is only count the most recent Act_no or Act_email for each duplicated Act_no or Act_email for the results of the last query (which I also need counts for) (Sorry if that is confusing).

So now that I know that doe@xx.com is in the table more than once, I need to count doe@xx.com just for the most recent call (So P_key 1) for Max.  Sue would have 1 most recent assigned dupes because mam@xx.com for p_key = 8 was a later call, but cat@xx.com was later than p_key = 8.  Joe would have two most recent because Act_no = 2 was later than P_key = 4,3, and 2, and mom@xx.com was later than p_key = 4.

So essentially what I am looking for is something similar to below

```
 Salesman | Count of Dupes | Most recent Dupe Assigned
   Max    |       3        |           1
   Sue    |       2        |           1
   Joe    |       2        |           2
```

This is what I have been working with thus far for the first part, but it really isn't getting to what I want, this is only limiting the counts to each salesman, not really count duplicates for the entire table for each salesman:

```
SELECT Salesman, COUNT(*)
FROM Table t
GROUP BY Salesman
HAVING COUNT(Act_No) > 1 OR  COUNT(Act_Email) > 1;
```

We are working with multiple clients and emails for each, and we want to change to combine commission payout for each salesman to only include distinct Act_No's and Emails.  So if an account or email talked to two salesman, we want the record to only count for the most recent salesman they talked to.

In short what I am hoping to due is to show for each salesman, how many duplicated act_no's and/or emails are for each, then show how many records each salesman would have if the most recent record was assigned to them.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this is confusing to me. What is your final goal in simple words ?

Comment: `but mom@xx.com or Act_No 5 exists more than once` I don't see that in your table. Is that correct or a mistake ?

Comment: sorry that was a typo...it should be x_x@xx.com and Act-No 4...I have rectified...I also added an explanation at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Does this query answer your first question? Let me know, and based on that I may be able to help with the second question.

```
WITH
  EmailCounts AS (
    SELECT Act_Email
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY Act_Email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ),
  ActCounts AS (
    SELECT Act_No
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY Act_No
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
SELECT
  Salesman,
  COUNT(COALESCE(EmailCounts.Act_Email, CAST(ActCounts.Act_No AS VARCHAR))) AS Dups
FROM [Table]
LEFT JOIN EmailCounts ON [Table].Act_Email = EmailCounts.Act_Email
LEFT JOIN ActCounts ON [Table].Act_No = ActCounts.Act_No
GROUP BY Salesman
```

*(Note: Your sample query names the table as "`Table`", which is a reserved word, so it has to be delimited with square brackets.)*

This query starts with a couple of "Common Table Expressions" (CTEs) - that's the `WITH EmailCounts AS ...` part - to get a list of duplicate emails and a list of duplicate account numbers.

Based on your sample data, the CTE results for emails would be:

```
Act_Email
----------
cat@xx.com
doe@xx.com
mom@xx.com
```

And the CTE results for account numbers would be account #2 only:

```
Act_No
------
2
```

The main query joins to the two lists by sales rep, and counts all rows where there's a non-null email or account number. Its intermediate results, before the `COUNT`, look like this:

```
Salesman Act_Email  Act_No
-------- ---------- ------
Max      doe@xx.com NULL    <- counted (email not null)
Max      doe@xx.com 2       <- counted (both not null)
Max      cat@xx.com 2       <- counted (both not null)
Sue      mom@xx.com 2       <- counted (both not null)
Sue      cat@xx.com NULL    <- counted (email not null)
Joe      NULL       NULL    <- not counted (both null)
Joe      mom@xx.com NULL    <- counted (email not null)
Joe      NULL       2       <- counted (act_no not null)
```

When the counting and grouping are applied, the result is this:

```
Salesman Dups
-------- ----
Joe      2
Max      3
Sue      2
```

[`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) will return the first non-null value it finds in its arguments, or NULL if all of the arguments are null. If it returns NULL, the `COUNT` won't count the row.

Also note that the `COALESCE` wouldn't work for me until I added the `CAST` for the account number to make it the same data type as the email.

Comment: That does help!  But the reason why Joe would be 2 is because mom@xx.com is duplicated, but Act_no 2 is also duplicated (P_keys2,3,4, and 7).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and sorry for missing the point about the account numbers - it was clearly in your original question. I've updated the query.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes a bunch of sense...works great!  So if I added the date time to that CTE's, then could I use that for the second part of my question?